# Check if a value in one table (X) is between the values in two columns in another table (Y) with R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Horrible title question, but this is what I am trying to achieve.  For Table1 I want to add the Column "BETWEEN", verifying if the "POSITION" falls between any of the "START" and "STOP" values for the corresponding "BIN" in Table2.

**Table1**. BIN names (character) and POSITION in BIN (numeric):

```
  BIN    POSITION
    1          12
    1          52
    1          86
    7           6
    7          22
    X         112
    X         139
   MT           3
   MT          26
```

**Table2**: BIN name (character) and START and STOP positions (numeric)

```
  BIN    START    STOP
    1        2      64
    1       90     110
    7       20     100
    7      105     200
    X        1       5
   MT        1    1000
```

And the desired result - Table 1 with "BETWEEN":

```
CHROM    POSITION      BETWEEN
    1          12         TRUE
    1          52         TRUE
    1          86        FALSE
    7           6        FALSE
    7          22         TRUE
    X         112        FALSE
    X         139        FALSE
   MT           3         TRUE
   MT          26         TRUE
```

My Table 1 has about 4,000,000 rows, and Table 2 about 500,000 rows, and anything I came up with was very slow.

As an example of bigger tables, use the following:

```
positions <- seq(1,100000,10)
bins <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J")

tab1 <- data.table(bin = rep(bins,1,each=length(positions)), pos = rep(positions,10))

tab2 <- data.table(bin = rep(bins,1,each=2000), start = seq(5,100000,50), stop = start+25)
```

The desired output would be:

```
tab1
        bin   pos    between
     1:   A     1    FALSE
     2:   A    11    TRUE
     3:   A    21    TRUE
     4:   A    31    FALSE
     5:   A    41    FALSE
```

Comment: If your BIN identifier is not a 1 to 1 match, how are your Table1 and Table2 of different size? You indicate that Bin 1 - Position is 86 is False. Can you explain why it is false? Because there isn't a third Chrom 1 in Table2? Why doesn't the second line of Table2, Bin1 Start 90 Stop 110 satisfy the condition.

Comment: @Vlo Each line in Table 1 is tested against all the matching BIN lines in Table 2 to produce a single output line which has BETWEEN=TRUE if any of the Table 2 START/STOP values enclose the Table 1 POSITION.

Comment: @Pete do the START and STOP pairs for a given BIN ever overlap? Is it sorted by START for a given BIN? Your example is like that for both those questions, but if its true in general you might be able to use binary searches to speed things up. Also, what are the largest values of START and STOP? If they aren't too huge then it might be possible to make a lookup table....

Comment: Bin 1 - Position 8 is FALSE because the START/STOP boundaries for Bin 1 in Table 2 are 2-64 and 90-110. 86 doesn't fall between those boundaries so it is FALSE

Comment: @Spacedman the START and STOP pairs within a BIN should not overlap (if they did they were collapses into a single row). BIN 1 is the largest with about 250,000,000 positions and about 350,000 ranges in Table 2.

Comment: BIN 1 has 250,000,000 positions? You said Table 1 only had 4,000,000 rows...

Comment: I read 86 as 96. See if possible solution below works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method requires that for a given bin, the bins are mutually exclusive.  (e.g. you cant have bin A with bounds 1-5 and another bin A with bounds 4-8.)  Also, I modified your example a bit.

```
positions <- seq(1,100000,10)
bins <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J")
tab1 <- data.table(bin = rep(bins,1,each=length(positions)), pos = rep(positions,10))
setkey(tab1,"bin","pos")

tab2 <- data.table(bin = rep(bins,1,each=2000), start = seq(5,100000,50))
tab2[, end := start+25]

tab2[,pos:=start]
setkey(tab2,"bin","pos")
x<-tab2[tab1, roll=TRUE, nomatch=0]

tab2[,pos:=end]
setkey(tab2,"bin","pos")
y<-tab2[tab1, roll=-Inf, nomatch=0]

setkey(x,"bin","pos","start")
setkey(y,"bin","pos","start")
inBin<-x[y,nomatch=0]
inBin[, between:=TRUE]

setkey(tab1,"bin","pos")
setkey(inBin,"bin","pos")

result<-inBin[,list(bin,pos,between)][tab1]
result[is.na(between), between:=FALSE]
```

I don't have the time to explain my solution in depth right now.  Instead I'll take the cheap way out and refer you to research the `roll` parameter of data.table.  The basic methodology above is that I'm joining tab1 and tab2, rolling pos forward to the nearest end bound.  Then I join tab1 and tab2, rolling pos backward to the nearest start bound.  Then I do an inner join on the those two sets, giving me all rows in tab1 which fall inside the bounds of a bin.  From that point, it's just grunt work.

Comment: This worked perfectly and was AMAZINGLY fast! In my example data, the system time was 0.06 seconds!

Comment: one follow up question would be can your example be modified to handle positions on the boundaries? For example, if the position was 5 or 30, and the start-stop was 5-30. Your solution would return TRUE for 5 and FALSE for 30 (which turns out to be the behavior I need). However, if you wanted to to be truly >=start and <=stop or >start and <stop could the roll functionality be modified to handle that?

Comment: @Pete I think you can alter the `rollends` argument of data.table to handle the edge cases or you could simply add 1 to right boundaries before applying the method above.  I'm sorry I'm not completely comfortable with rolling joins at the moment, but I plan on doing some research and posting an article about them on my blog in the next couple of weeks http://gormanalysis.com/

Comment: @Pete I completed my article on rolling joins today http://gormanalysis.com/?p=176

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward approach is to nest the matching loops I think. You may be need to handle factors slightly differently. I haven't tested to see what happens if it does not find a bin match.

```
BIN <- c("1","1","1","7","7","X","X","MT","MT")
POSITION <- c(12,52,86,6,22,112,139,3,26)
npos <- length(POSITION)
BETWEEN <- vector(mode="logical",length=npos)
tab1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(BIN,POSITION))

BIN2 <- c("1","1","7","7","X","MT")
START <- c(2,90,20,105,1,1)
STOP <- c(64,110,100,200,5,1000)
tab2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(BIN2,START,STOP))

bins <- unique(tab1$BIN)

for(bin in bins){
  #print(paste("bin=",bin))
  t1.bin.matches <- which(tab1$BIN==bin)
  t2.bin.compares <- which(tab2$BIN2==bin)
  #print(t1.bin.matches)
  #print(t2.bin.compares)
  for(match in t1.bin.matches){
    between = FALSE
    candidate = as.numeric(as.vector(tab1$POSITION)[match])
    for(compare in t2.bin.compares){
      comp.start <- as.numeric(as.vector(tab2$START)[compare])
      comp.stop <- as.numeric(as.vector(tab2$STOP)[compare])
      if(candidate>=comp.start&&candidate<=comp.stop){
        between = TRUE
        break
      }
    }
    #print(paste(comp.start,candidate,comp.stop,between))
    BETWEEN[match] = between
  }
}
tab1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(tab1,BETWEEN))
tab1
```

Comment: You can drop out of your inner loop as soon as you find the first `between=TRUE` match since if there's more than one then the answer is still TRUE.

Comment: I mentioned that above the code but did not implement, I will edit to add a break statement.

Comment: Thanks @tom.purucker the solution gives the right result, but it does not work with my larger tables. For tables with 1000 rows in each it worked great, about 13 seconds, with 10,000 rows though it was 1100 seconds, with 100,000 rows I killed it after four hours (my real data set has closer to 4 million rows!).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your BIN columns are character, POSITION, START, END are numeric.

```
Table1$BIN = as.character(Table1$BIN)
Table1$POSITION = as.numeric(Table1$POSITION)
Table2$BIN = as.character(Table2$BIN)
Table2$START = as.numeric(Table2$START)
Table2$STOP = as.numeric(Table2$STOP)
```

Convert your data.frame to library(data.table) because the code below might be slow.

```
Table1 = as.data.table(Table1)
Table2 = as.data.table(Table2)
```

Generate desired output

```
z = apply(Table1, 1, function(x) {nrow(Table2[(as.numeric(x[2])>START) & (as.numeric(x[2])<STOP) & (BIN == as.character(x[1])),])>0})
cbind(Table1, z)
```

Old function is z(), new is y(). With the sample Table1, Table2, the new function is 30% faster. I don't know how this advantage will scale as nrow increases, but I'm guessing this scaling will be very positive. Let me know.

```
z = function(a){apply(Table1, 1, function(x) {z = subset(Table2, Table2$BIN == as.character(x[1])) 
                                                  any(as.numeric(x[2])>z$START & as.numeric(x[2])<z$STOP)})}

y = function(a){apply(Table1, 1, function(x) {nrow(Table2[(as.numeric(x[2])>START) & (as.numeric(x[2])<STOP) & (BIN == as.character(x[1])),])>0})}


microbenchmark(z(), y(), times = 1000L)

 expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
  z() 1168.283 1219.793 1237.791 1276.267 3481.576  1000
  y()  809.575  848.052  863.257  885.909 1683.383  1000
```

edit: you might need to muck with the as.numeric, and as.character in the subsetting. I lost the data.table I created earlier and directly used the answer above's data.frame.

Comment: This worked well with 10,000 rows (about 20 seconds) but got really slow with 100,000 rows (I'll update the comment later with a time if it finishes).

Comment: That might be a real problem. `aaply` can be used over apply, probably will offer some minor speed increase. But I think the code can be greatly improved by essentially moving/translating `any(as.numeric(x[2])>z$START & as.numeric(x[2])<z$STOP)})` into the `subset.data.table` step. Let me know if that speeds up the code.

Comment: Couldn't get `aaply` to work for some reason. Edited code above to do all testing and subsetting within data.table. If this is still painfully slow, you should probably contact the author `data.table`. He posts here.